# Xamarin Forms Iphone X remove padding

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've tried everything to remove the top padding in IPhone X, including setting this on the page code behind:

```
   var safeInsets = On<iOS>().SafeAreaInsets();
        safeInsets.Top = 0;
        Padding = safeInsets;
```

and in Xaml

```
       xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
         ios:Page.UseSafeArea="False"   
         ios:Page.PrefersStatusBarHidden="True" 
         NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
```

Still getting this padding at the top.  I'm probably missing or not understanding something.  I've read all the Xamarin guides, many forum posts, etc.  How do I get the image to go all the way to the top?

[image]

Comment: You talking about this notch at the top? this is by default in new Iphones, u cant get rid of it. U r running iPhone X emualtor, so this one has that for sure.

Comment: Not the notch, the white padding at the top of the page even though safe area is not enabled

Comment: Hi @PatrickGoode did you launch your app from an image or a LaunchScreen xib ? If you are'nt using a LaunchScreen consider use one, but if you already using one, just edit on xcode to fill entire screen.

Comment: Not getting it.. in the image you are showing it's all fine..

Comment: @PatrickGoode which white Padding? There is a kinda black padding in left and right corner. Can't see the black padding.

Comment: Sorry i meant to say White padding. I think u meant that big white space that literally look like a part of the image? It looks like a sky on that image? is that the case? :D

Comment: I got this to work but I don't know how.  So confusing.

Comment: @Patrick Did you find a solution?